# I want to save a channel's id in database to use it in loggings

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is my code

```
@logs.command()
async def channel(ctx,channel=discord.TextChannel):
    data=await client.file.find(ctx.guild.id)
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_guild:
        if channel==None:
            await ctx.send("Mention or use the ID of the channel to set as logging channel.")
        else:
            await client.file.upsert({"_id":ctx.guild.id,"log_channel":channel.id})
            await ctx.send(f"{channel.mention} is set as the logging channel.")
    else:
        e=discord.Embed(description="You dont have `MANAGE GUILD` permission to set the logging channel",color=0xFF0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

when I try to run the command in this format (T.logs channel #channel) I keep getting this error -

```
(Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'id')
```

I want to save the mentioned channel id in database for further uses

Comment: We can't help you without seeing more of your code. I'd assume `channel` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'id'
```

stems from something trying to read an `id` attribute from a string.
Looking at your code, that's likely to be `channel`, and indeed, you're [defaulting the `channel` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) to `discord.TextChannel`, which is most likely a string:

```
async def channel(ctx,channel=discord.TextChannel):
```

That looks like you may have been looking for a type annotation, i.e.

```
async def channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
```

(but it's unlikely you'd want an `str` for the type either).

Comment: Thanks !! it worked. I didnt noticed = instead of :
silly mistake -_-